# React.default.memo is not a function (React-Native) wrapWithConnect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I get this the error

> _react.default.memo is not a function

and `wrapWithConnect`.
This is a `react-native` project and it worked fine before I used the connect function to connect my dispatch into my react component:

Package Versions:

```
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
```

code

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
 return { 
  sendEmail: (email, navigateMap) => dispatch(sendEmail, navigateMap))

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Login)
```

Answer (score 30):

I had the same problem and I changed the version of `react-redux` to `6.0.0` instead of using a more recent one, and the issue was resolved.

You can change the version by running following command:

`npm install react-redux@6.0.0`.

My project version is greater than 16.5.0 but I am unsure if this also has an impact or not.

Comment: Tried this and it throws the error: Unable to resolve module ''./utils/batch'....

Comment: Next step is to `expo r -c ` per this issue: https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1247

Comment: yep dont forget Next step is to `expo r -c`  after switch back 6.0.0

Answer (score 6):

Had this exact same error. Realised it's not due to syntax errors, but the react-redux version compabitility. Once I ran yarn check, it gave me multiple messages that "react-redux#react@^16.8.4 does not satisfy found match of react@16.5.0".

Expo is react 16.5.0 while react-redux expects react version 16.8.4 . As moi answered, installing react-redux 6.0.0 worked for me. Trying to change any other package caused even more errors to appear

Answer (score 5):

Try using react 16.6.0 instead of 16.5.0

Answer (score 4):

This is issue with expo.Try to clear expo cache by using this command

`expo r -c`

Answer (score 2):

Try update your dependencies.

I have the same problem and I'm using [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates).

Here's a update check log:

```
 expo               ^32.0.0  →  ^32.0.6
 react               16.5.0  →   16.8.6
 react-navigation    ^3.6.1  →   ^3.7.1
 babel-preset-expo   ^5.0.0  →   ^5.1.1

Run npm install to install new versions.
```

Comment: And sometimes I have to delete all node_modules and reinstall.

Answer (score 2):

If you are feeling lost and shelterless while trying to implement a modern React-Native inside Expo app, do not worry my friend, you are not alone.

I had this problem and found that:

- `expo 32.0` does not support `react 16.8`
- `react-redux 7.1` and on require `react 16.8`

I was able to make it work with this set of versions:

```
"expo": "^32.0.0",
"react": "16.5.0",
"react-redux": "^6.0.1",
```

You can replace them in your `package.json`, then you should do:

```
> rm -rf node_modules
> [npm|yarn] install
> expo r -c
```

In order to remove previous versions from node_modules and Expo cache.

Answer (score 1):

To combine the two answers that solved it for me:

1. Remove new react-redux: `yarn remove react-redux`
2. Install the older version of react-redux: `yarn add react-redux@6.0.1`
3. Clear expo cache: `expo r -c`

That will do the trick.