# _react.default.memo is not a function | wrapWithConnect issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

When wrapping a component with connect()(Component), I am getting an error on my React Native application. "_react.default.memo is not a function (In _react.default.memo(ConnectFunction), _react.default.memo is undefined. How can I resolve this issue?

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9miSR.jpg)

I believe this issue is based on my version numbers with React and Redux. But I am unable to locate the culprit. This application is in very early development, but perhaps I just forgot to connect something with my store.

Currently my versions from package.json are the following

```
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^32.0.6",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^3.8.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.1.1",
    "schedule": "^0.4.0"
  }
```

I have tried rolling back react-redux to 6.0.0 and react to 16.5.0 as described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55624579/react-default-memo-is-not-a-function-react-native-wrapwithconnect) but, I get a different error.

```
Unable to resolve "./utils/batch" from "node_modules/react-redux/lib/index.js"
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling react-redux. (including deleting the folder). I don't even see a call to utils/batch inside that index.js file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The component renders correctly before `connect` is added. Exception happens when `export default connect()(ComponentName)` is invoked.

if needed, my repository is found [here](https://github.com/Foxifly/Native-Flashcards). Since then, though, I have toyed with the versions.

Comment: if someone is getting here with the same problem _without_ the _native_ part (just in the browser), be sure to check that your dependencies have compatible versions ([see here](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1239#issuecomment-493747124)). For me, it worked as soon as I upgraded to the latest version of React and Redux

Answer (score 4):

Switching to React Redux 6.0.0 `npm install react-redux@6.0.0`.

In order to get rid of the `Unable to resolve "./utils/batch" from "node_modules/react-redux/lib/index.js"`

Clear expo caches with `expo r -c`.

https://forums.expo.io/t/how-to-clear-the-react-native-packager/1352

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a specific answer backed with references. If you have a suggestion or need clarification leave a comment. We have guidelines on [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I think I was just able to resolve this. I finally caved and installed `yarn` letting Yarn take over the dependency install seemed to have worked.

My dependencies are running at

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^32.0.6",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^3.8.1",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.1.1",
    "schedule": "^0.4.0"
  },
```

and my app is back to running with everything acting compatible again. Not sure what was done differently with Yarn. But I am relieved that I got this back up. I hope this helps others!

Comment: Have you checked if your component rerenders if the state mapped to props  changes ?